# How I can manage to show large sum of images in imageview of fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am developing a book app. It contains 13 chapters, each chapter contains many (7-10) exercises and each exercise contains many images(10-15).

I have created main menu activity which contains all the 13 chapters.
I have created 2 fragments, one to show exercises and 2nd for the imageview.

1) Which is the best place to put 400 images? they r very small size like 10kb per image so I want include them in apk. in raw i can access them through their id, while i can create chapter folders in asset which contains exercises folders which contain images.
but then i would have to use asset manager.

2) How I can create arraylists of exercises for each chapter? in xml of in java? and how i can use one fragment to access these arraylists and display exercises as buttons so user can click on it to load images.

3) how I can load multiple (10-15) images in a single imageview in scrollview for each exercise?

if u need to ask for any details please  do ask.

Comment: IMHO, This becomes too broad. Please narrow down to a single question at a time.

Comment: first question is pretty basic, u can just answer 2nd question :)

Comment: 1) Add images to 'res>drawable' folder. I think you could make a file name as 'c01_001.png'.
2) SQLite for your chapter data. When you need exercises for each chapter,  just query.
3) Make a scrollView and inflate each image programmatically.

Comment: Create Static ArrayList<YourObject> OR You can use sqlite database. For loading use onScroll loading which is better for performance.

Comment: @Charles can u please show me a way how i can assign images to each exercise? by putting images in drawable and making TypedArrays for each exercise of each chapter? if yes then how i can assign them from fragmentA exercises to my fragmentB listview? thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I recommend you to use [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to manage the images.

2) You can stock the information in json files and the parse them with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or similar (It would be better if you stock it in a database and then use an [ORM](http://greendao-orm.com/) to retrieve it).

3) You can't. You should use [ListView](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) against.

Comment: cant i just create arraylist for each chapter in xml?

Comment: personally I prefer json, but yes you can. we are talking just the way to stock structured information. but with gson its just one line for parse your array. Please read a little about and then you can choise ;)